# LinkedHashSet remove duplicates object

Tags: java, collections, set

I have simple question to you, I have class Product that have fields like this:

```
private Integer id;
private String category;
private String symbol;
private String desc;
private Double price;
private Integer quantity;
```

I want to remove duplicates item from LinkedHasSet based on ID, e.g Products that have same ID but diffrent quantity will be add to set, I want to remove (update) products with same ID, and it will by my unique id of object, how to do that?

e.g
Product: id=1, category=CCTV, symbol=TVC-DS, desc=Simple Camera, price=100.00, **quantity=1**
Product: id=1, category=CCTV, symbol=TVC-DS, desc=Simple Camera, price=100.00, **quantity=3**

won't be added to set

my code:

```
    public void setList(Set<Product> list) {
    if(list.isEmpty()) 
        this.list = list;
    else {
        this.list.addAll(list);
        Iterator<Product> it = this.list.iterator();
        for(Product p : list) {
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                if(it.next().getId() != p.getId())
                    it.remove();
                    this.list.add(p);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't really understand: the set can only contain products that have different IDs, whatever their other attributes (quantity, but also category, symbol, etc.), right?

Comment: Yes, unique ID of object will be Product.id

Comment: This all about your `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation. try to override these methods in a proper way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All `Set` implementations remove duplicates, and the `LinkedHashSet` is no exception.

The definition of duplicate is two objects that are equal to each other, according to their `equals()` method.  If you haven't overridden `equals` on your `Product` class, then only identical references will be considered equal - not different instances with the same values.

So you need to add a more specific implementation of `equals` (and `hashcode`) for your class.  For some examples and guidance, see [Overriding equals and hashcode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).  (Note that you **must** override `hashcode` as well, otherwise your class will not behave correctly in hash sets.)

Comment: I have equal and hashCode methods generated by eclipse, so I must use Obj.equal(Obj) style ?

Comment: No, the LinkedHashSet will call `equals` itself internally, and will not insert an element that is equal to one already in the set.  If you're seeing "duplicates" in your set, then the equals method must not be defined how you expect - you must have two duplicates `a` and `b` such that `a.equals(b)` returns false.  (Or, since it's a hash-based set, `a.hashCode() != b.hashCode()`)

Comment: You can retain the default overridden hashcode implementation from eclipse, your Product class should have the logic of returning false when the productId is equal when compared with another object, and all other properties can be left unchecked for equality... Dont forget to handle transitive, reflexive and symmetric equlality for objects

Comment: but how to do that when in equals method signature I must have Object type, and compiler don't know that it will be Product. I can not use generic in method signature because it won't be overridden

Comment: @user1853125 That's how the method is defined, because you can compare equality against any object.  Typically, implementations will check whether the other object is the same class - if not, they immediately return `false`, otherwise they cast to `Product` and go on to compare fields.  If you have a look at start of the Eclipse-generated code, it's almost certainly doing something like this.  You just need to change the logic that compares fields.

Comment: ok, I wrote something like this: `@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if(!(obj instanceof Product))
   return false;  Product p = (Product) obj;
  if(this.id.hashCode() == p.id.hashCode() ) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }` and its works properly

Comment: strange, equals works, but LinkedHashSet still adds same-id objects ;/

Comment: @user1853125 Your `equals()` method is implemented wrong. You should compare object's fields, not the `hashCode()` result. There is a chance that completely different objects return the same hash code. You should first learn how hashtables work and why it is important to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly. Irrespective of that, even if you implement `equals()` properly, you've got design issues in the code, which will cause other problems later

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you straight answer, but a couple of advices.

1. If you want to put `Product` in a `Set` you need to implement its `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.
2. When implementing `equals()` you will have to decide **what "equality" for a `Product` means**, (`Set` can contain only one instance in terms on "equality"). For instance, if two `Product` instances are "equal" is it enough if they have the same **ID** or should we also take **quantity** into account?. It's not easy to answer this question in your case, but please read on.
3. Normally in situation like this only ID is taken into account. In that case you shouldn't have two `Product` instances in memory with different `quantities`, because one of them would represent a state that is incorrect (ie. particular product's quantity can be either 1 or 3, not both at a time).
4. I think the design is not fully correct. `Product` class in your case represents a general product description (including price), so `quantity` doesn't really fit there. If someone can order a couple of copies of `Product` I think you should create another class such as `Order` or `OrderLine` which specifies what product is ordered and the corresponding quantity, eg:

   > ```
   > class OrderLine {
   >   private Product product;
   >   private Integer quantity; 
   > }
   > ```

   With design like this it's easy to answer question from point 2. `Product.equals()` should compare the ID only, and `OrderLine.equals()` both the product (ID) **and** quantity.

Comment: so I must create `Order` class with simple setter and getter methods and adds overriden hashCode and equals methods?

Comment: I use Product class with quantity because I use it in Datatable component with selector column, so it quite difficult to implement it by using two class.

Comment: @user1853125 I don't fully understand what "Datatable component with selector column" is, but if you have just single table which contains both the product description, price and quantity, then the DB design is also wrong and it's probably the root of your problems. You should have one table for Product (and its descriptions) and another one for Orders (that has a foreign key to Product, and a quantity column). The Order usually has its own ID too.

Comment: but when I have OrderLine class i must to create new `equals` and `hashCode` methods to define unique ID, that's really complicated

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you implement your own hash function in a way that it hashes elements with equal ID-s with the same code. This will solve your issue, without you having to code it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be adding to the list twice.  Once during the `addAll()` call then once again during the iteration.  In this case I believe the second iteration would suffice.  The comparison should also be modified to use `equals` instead of `==`

```
public void setList(Set<Product> list) {
    if(list.isEmpty()) 
        this.list = list;
    else {
        //this.list.addAll(list); Do not add all
        Iterator<Product> it = this.list.iterator();
        for(Product p : list) {
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                if(it.next().getId().equals(p.getId()))
                {
                    this.list.add(p);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, you will need to implement (override) `equals()`, `hashCode()` and (prefarably) `compareTo()` from `Comparable` interface. These methods, if not implemented correctly can lead to unexpected runtime behavior. Hard to debug issues. Hence, I suggest you use `Apache Commons` `EqualsBuilder`, `HashcodeBuilder` and `ComparableBuilder` to implement these methods. An example of how to use `Apache Commons builder` can be seen in this link http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/1859